# Wrapping a DOM-Element creating external library with a Vue Component with Slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm integrating a heavy-duty third party DOM-manipulating library into my large Vue application. That library provides a SVG element that it creates and hooks into internal transform events that I then am able to add svg elements to. I want to wrap that library in a component in a way that I can provide slotted SVG vue components to it as children

I'm finding a lot of simple examples of how to wrap a third party component with a vue component, but I've found absolutely nothing about intermixing existing HTML with the return value of the render function.

I want to be able to use this sort structure, albeit in a more complex fashion:

parent

```
<template lang="pug">
    div
        third-party-svg-wrapper(:props="props")
            g
                custom-svg-rect(:v-for="rect of rects")
</template>
```

Wrapper Component

```
export default {
    name: 'third-party-svg-wrapper',
    created(){
        this.$options.wrapper = Document.createElement('div') 
        this.$options.nonReactiveThirdPartySVGTool = thirdPartySVGTool({
            element:this.$options.wrapper,
        });
    },
    render(createElement) {
        let locationForSlot = this.$options.wrapper.querySelector(`svg`);
        // this obviously doesn't work, because this.$slots.default is 
        // not a DOM Node. However, it's a representation 
        // of what I want to do, appending the slot 
        // to the correct location in the third party html
        locationForSlot.appendChild(this.$slots.default)
        return createElement(
            'svg',
            this.$options.wrapper
        );
    }
}
```

The ideal result would have the SVG element created as expected by the thirdPartySVGTool, which would then reactively render the slots placed in the svg component it generated.

Is this possible? If so, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was barking up the wrong tree. The best way to do this is to just move the component elements into the correct location after they're mounted. Vue cares about the data dependency relationship between components, but it only cares about the HTML structure in how a single component handles its own templating. So changing the location of the base level reference of that component doesn't hinder that component's operation or rendering.

here's the code for the working component

```
<template lang="pug">
    div.svg-overlay-wrapper
        svg.temp-slotted-svg(:v-show='false')
            slot
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'third-party-svg-overlay',
    props:{
        thirdPartyModuleInstance:{
            required: true,
        },
        overlayConfig:{
            required: false,
        }
    },
    data(){
        return { _svg_overlay:{} };
    },
    created(){
        this.$options._svg_overlay = this.thirdPartyModuleInstance.svgOverlay(this.overlayConfig);
    },
    mounted(){
        for(let slot of this.$slots.default){
            let targetElement = slot.$el || slot.elm;
            this.$options._svg_overlay._node.appendChild(targetElement);
        }
    },
    watch:{
        '$slots.default'(newVal, oldVal){
            if(newVal.length > oldVal.length){
                for(let i = oldVal.length; i < newVal.length; i++){
                    let targetElement = slot.$el || slot.elm;
                    this.$options._svg_overlay._node.appendChild(targetElement);
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful for me since I'm trying to wrap an existing DOM element (managed with a native javascript object/class) into a vue wrapper. Basicly all I need to do now is write the interface bewteen the JS object and the new vue object.